# How to build code in to one jar an all maven dependencies into another jar in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a maven project where when i build pom.xml all code goes into one jar(cde.jar) and all dependencies which i mention in pom.xml should get generated into another jar(dpe.jar).Please update how to achieve this.

Comment: Why not just put everything into one jar?

Comment: Why do you want something like this

Comment: when i try to put everything into one jar by using assembly plugin or some other way, all dependencies are not getting extracted. more over it was the requirement

Comment: So the technical problems with the assembly plugin should be solvable. Where does the requirement come from? What is the reason behind it?

Comment: I am trying to convert Ant project into Maven Project. The war file generated in Ant build having code into one jar file and all Ant jars into another jar file finally both build into a war file. I would like to achieve the same in maven project then only i can deploy package in App server

Comment: If you have several JAR's you can do that via maven-war-plugin / maven-jar-pugin which means having separate modules which produce the appropriate jar file...that's the usual way to do that. Convention over Configuration which I strongly to recommend to follow otherwise your migration will not really work. ..

Comment: Hi .  i am already using jar and war plugins. Using jar plugin i am buildings entire source code in to a jar file and copying it into war file using war plugin.  my requirement is i wanted to build all dependencies in to another jar file and copy it into war file so that code will be in one jar and dependencies in to another jar finally both will be in war file. I am able to download all dependencies in to a folder inside target folder.but i don't know how to convert them in to a jar file through maven build